# how to delete a particular element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a function to create a new box when I click 'add new box' button and after that, it will also able to delete the box when I click the particular delete button which is related with the box. How to make the function in javascript? Should I save in an array for every new element that it creates?

My code:

```js
function addBox() {
  var el = document.getElementById('target');
  var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
  var frame = document.getElementById('container');
  var attr = document.createAttribute('val');
  attr.value = 'demo';
  el.setAttributeNode(attr);
  frame.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="target" class="foo" val="demo">
    <div class="content" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:orange;margin:1px" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addBox();">Add box</button>
<button onclick="deleteBox();">Delete box</button>
```

I wanted to be like this!

[image]

Comment: Why not adding id to button when you are creating a new one. And onclick you can take it and remove tnusing `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the button element using `this` as an argument on the `deleteBox()` function and then the parent of the button by using `parentNode` and then apply `remove()` method on it:

```js
function addBox() {
  var el = document.getElementById('target');
  var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
  var frame = document.getElementById('container');
  var attr = document.createAttribute('val');
  attr.value = 'demo';
  el.setAttributeNode(attr);
  frame.appendChild(clone);
}

function deleteBox(e){
  e.parentNode.remove()
}
```

```css
.content{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #F5A623;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="target" class="foo" val="demo">
    <div class="content" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:orange;margin:1px"></div>
    <button onclick="deleteBox(this);">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addBox();">Add box</button>
```

As a sidenote, I strongly recommend you to have unique ids on elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="target" class="foo" val="demo">
        <div class="content">aaa</div>
        <button onclick="deleteBox(this);">Delete box</button>
      </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addBox();">Add box</button>


function addBox() {
  var el = document.getElementById('target');
  var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
  var frame = document.getElementById('container');
  var attr = document.createAttribute('val');
  attr.value = 'demo';
  el.setAttributeNode(attr);
  frame.appendChild(clone);
}
function deleteBox(obj){
    obj.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery:

```
function deleteBox(){
   $( "#target" ).remove();
}
```

Javascript:

```
function deleteBox(){
   document.getElementById('target').remove()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is alternative example, You can try in your code :)

```
var sentenceIndex = 1;
        function addSentence() {            
            var n = sentenceIndex;
            var html = '<div class="form-item-wrap" id="sentencebox' + n + '">'+
            '<div class="form-item">'+
            '<input class="form-control" type="text" id="sentence'+n+'" name="sentence[' + n + ']">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="course-region-tool">'+
            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeSentence('+n+');" class="delete" title="delete">'+
            '<i class="icon md-recycle"></i></a></div></div>';
            $("#addSentenceDiv").append(html);
            sentenceIndex = sentenceIndex + 1;
        }
        function removeSentence(id) {
            console.log(id);
            $("#sentencebox"+id).remove();
        }
```